# Eclipse Kepler Force.IDE, cant Deploy objects to new ORG

Tags: eclipse, object, deployment, salesforce, issue-tracking

I have a carpet with full working salesforce org, but now i want to deploy into new ORG, when i start deploying the objects into the new ORG i validate them and it give me success for deploying, so later click next and still give me success for it.

The issue is when i search for new custom object into the org and there is no result for them. can anyone give a little hint on what's should be wrong about this?

PD: By the way i checked if i was using wrong credential to new org and is not that.

Comment: What are you using for migration? Are both system configurations same(Sandbox-Sandbox, Prod-Prod, Dev-Dev)?

Comment: ty for your time , but i figure out later that all my carpets were empty and i dont know why...